# The method getRequestCode() is undefined for the type SelectionFragment

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Excuse me, 
I want to try facebook developer for android Tutorial. at [Show Friends](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/show-friends/) part.
I have succeed doing Step [hello Scrumptious](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/), [Autenticate with login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/) and [personalize](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/personalize/) part.
At Show Friends part, I get error

> The method getRequestCode() is undefined for the type
>   SelectionFragment

I use API level 17 before. Then try to change to API Level 10, I get many errors. And I change to API Level 8, then, the previous error appears. getRequestCode() method is still not working.

Can You help me to give any clue error? I have try to search at internet but, really I do not know what is the problem. I try to re-read the tutorial, make new project, and trying then still fails for many times.

Please help.

Thank You.

```
package com.firstfbapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView;

public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "SelectionFragment";
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView userNameView;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private ListView listView;
    private List<BaseListElement> listElements;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state,
                final Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };
    private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do nothing for now
        startPickerActivity(PickerActivity.FRIEND_PICKER, getRequestCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Do nothing for now
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection, container, false);
        // Check for an open session
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data
            makeMeRequest(session);
        }
        // Find the user's profile picture custom view
        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.selection_profile_pic);
        profilePictureView.setCropped(true);

        // Find the user's name view
        userNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selection_user_name);
        // Find the list view
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.selection_list);

        // Set up the list view items, based on a list of
        // BaseListElement items
        listElements = new ArrayList<BaseListElement>();
        // Add an item for the friend picker
        listElements.add(new PeopleListElement(0));
        // Set the list view adapter
        listView.setAdapter(new ActionListAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.id.selection_list, listElements));

        return view;
    }

    private void startPickerActivity(Uri data, int requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setData(data);
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), PickerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
        // Make an API call to get user data and define a
        // new callback to handle the response.
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        // If the response is successful
                        if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                                // view that in turn displays the profile
                                // picture.
                                profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                                // Set the Textview's text to the user's name.
                                userNameView.setText(user.getName());
                            }
                        }
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            // Handle errors, will do so later.
                        }
                    }
                });
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session,
            SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            // Get the user's data.
            makeMeRequest(session);
        }
    }

    private class ActionListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BaseListElement> {
        private List<BaseListElement> listElements;

        public ActionListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                List<BaseListElement> listElements) {
            super(context, resourceId, listElements);
            this.listElements = listElements;
            // Set up as an observer for list item changes to
            // refresh the view.
            for (int i = 0; i < listElements.size(); i++) {
                listElements.get(i).setAdapter(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
            }

            BaseListElement listElement = listElements.get(position);
            if (listElement != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(listElement.getOnClickListener());
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                if (icon != null) {
                    icon.setImageDrawable(listElement.getIcon());
                }
                if (text1 != null) {
                    text1.setText(listElement.getText1());
                }
                if (text2 != null) {
                    text2.setText(listElement.getText2());
                }
            }
            return view;
        }

    }

    private class PeopleListElement extends BaseListElement {

        public PeopleListElement(int requestCode) {
            super(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.action_people), getActivity().getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.action_people), getActivity()
                    .getResources().getString(R.string.action_people_default),
                    requestCode);
        }

        @Override
        protected View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener() {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Do nothing for now
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant part of the code related to the `SelectionFragment`. However that message simply explain that there isn't any `getRequestCode` method for the `SelectionFragment` class

Comment: Oh, yes, Sir.. I have attached the code. Please review, and please give advice. Thank You.

Comment: What getRequestCode does? Are you sure it's not getTargetRequestCode?

Comment: Please check this tutorial Sir..
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/show-friends/

on that tutorial getRequestCode() method.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you have to extend `FragmentActivity` and not `Fragment` as said in the tutorial: "*First, create a new class in your package named ''PickerActivity'' that subclasses FragmentActivity.*"
Second you call the `getRequestCode()` in the `onClick` of the fragment and not in the one of `PeopleListElement`.

Comment: My PickerActivity has already subclass of FragmentActivity, Sir.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed app the class definition.. but the second part of my answer is right, the `getRequestCode()` is a method of the `BaseListElement`, and you put it in the `onClick` of the fragment.

Comment: maybe I wrong put the onClick method at SelectionFragment class. So, where should I put that onClick method?

Comment: You should move that code in the onClick method of the PeopleListElement class.. the last one in the code that you posted here.

Comment: I move that onClick method to PeopleListElement class, but same error message still appears, Sir. Still not working, really, I do not know, what is getRequestCode() method? Why that code appears at the documentation?

Comment: Of course you have also to remove it from the fragment class.

Comment: "I move that onClick method to PeopleListElement class" it means onClick method at SelectionFragment class has already removed. And getRequestCode() error is appears at inner class at PeopleListElement class.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense to me, because your PeopleListElement extends BaseListElement which, in fact, has the method getRequestCode() as you can see from [here](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/BaseListElement.java)

Comment: Oh, right Sir.. But, that additional method getRequestCode() is not printed at previous tutorial, but printed at that part, and not give command to add getRequestCode() method at BaseListElement. Thank You very much, Sir.

Comment: My pleasure.. and if you want you can choose the answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

I modify PeopleListElement as the following

```
private class PeopleListElement extends BaseListElement {
    private int requestCode;
    public PeopleListElement(int requestCode) {
        super(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_people),
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.action_people),
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.action_people_default),
                requestCode);
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startPickerActivity(PickerActivity.FRIEND_PICKER, requestCode);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I declare a variable named "requestCode" in PeopleListElement. This variable is assigned a value whenever PeopleListElement's constructor is called. Then I replace getRequestCode() with "requestCode".